# Pesky end of input error in rails layout?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am getting this error message: /app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:29: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input end ^

And I've inserted all kinds of end / <% end %> s and I can't get it to work.  Here is my _header layout partial where the error is occuring.  The debugging window says the error occurs on the last line with <% end %>.  Thanks for the help.

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <%= link_to "Health for the Future", root_path, id: "logo" %>
  <nav>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
    <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "About",   about_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Store", products_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Testimonials", testimonials_path %></li> 
    <% user_signed_in? %>
      <li><%= link_to "Users", users_path %></li>
      <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
          Account <b class="caret"></b>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_path(current_user) %></li>

          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li>
            <%= link_to "Log out", logout_path %>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    <% else %>
      <li><%= link_to "Log in", login_path %></li>
    <% end %>

      </ul>
    </nav>
   </div>

 </header>

  <% end %>
```

Comment: There is no matching block for your last end. Remove it and try.

Comment: That was how I originally had it, but that yields this error:      /app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:37: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<% user_signed_in? %>
```

should be

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
```

And I don't see a matching block for your last end.